# Runtime Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that removes trailing spaces/tabs from input lines (Exercise 1-18 from K&R).

```
/* Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each
line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines. */

#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int gettline(char s[], int lim);

main()
{
    int len, i;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    while ((len = gettline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        for(i=0; i<len-1; ++i){
            if (line[i]!= ' ' && line[i]!='\t')
                printf("%s", line[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");   
    return 0;
}

/* gettline: read a line into s, return length */
int gettline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

When I run it I get the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I viewed some other SO questions with the same theme ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457979/core-dumped-in-c-programming), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323148/segmentation-fault-core-dump), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575323/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-error-in-c), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641597/what-is-segmentation-fault-core-dumped),..) but they were too complex for my level. I only know that the error means I tried to access part of the memory I wasn't allowed to. I am not sure where exactly this happened in my case

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `fgets` to read your file line by line?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am a total beginner in C and I am reading K&R from the beginning. I am supposed to solve the problem with no use of libraries. 

@Vladp Hm, no. I only ran it through valgrind and it gave no errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the seg fault should be this:

```
    for(i=0; i<len-1; ++i){
        if (line[i]!= ' ' && line[i]!='\t')
            printf("%s", line[i]); 
    }
```

Because of `%s`, `printf()` expects a `char *` argument but you pass a single character.
Change it to `printf( "%c", line[i] );` and it should run.

**But**
it still wouldn't do what you say you want to achieve ("remove trailing spaces/tabs") because you wouldn't print *any* spaces or tabs, "  Hello World  " would become "HelloWorld"